# How to get a MLMultiArray output in Vision with my CoreML model

Tags: python, swift, coreml, vision

I am trying to use my CoreMl model with the Vision framework in swift. My model outputs a MLMultiArray. When I run it through Vision I do get an output, however the output is of type VNObservation, and I am unable to use it and unable to convert it to an MLMultiArray. Does anyone know how to get an MLMultiArray as an output, or convert VNObservation to an MLMultiArray? Thank you!!

My code is showing the function captureOutput of a AVCaptureSession (Camera), each capture frame (sampleBuffer) is being processed by the model.

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    guard let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {return}
    
    guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for:mobilenet_v2_nail_model_update().model) else {
        print("returned huh")
        return}

    let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) {
        finishReq, err in
        
        guard let results = finishReq.results as? [VNObservation] else { return }
        
        guard let vnObservationObject = results.first as? VNObservation else { return }
        
        //this is where I am stuck, cannot convert result into MLMultiArray
    }

    do {
        try VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: [:]).perform([request])
        
        if let mlMultiArray = self.currentMLArray {
            let aWidth = CGFloat(mlMultiArray.shape[0].intValue)
            let aHeight = CGFloat(mlMultiArray.shape[1].intValue)
            
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(
                CGSize(width: aWidth, height: aHeight))
            if let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
                
                ctx.clear(CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: Double(aWidth), height: Double(aHeight)));
                
                for j in 0..<Int(aHeight) {
                    for i in 0..<Int(aWidth) {
                        let aValue = (mlMultiArray[j * Int(aHeight) + i].floatValue >= 0.5) ?
                        1.0 : 0.0
                        
                        let aRect = CGRect(
                            x: CGFloat(i),
                            y: CGFloat(j),
                            width: 1.0,
                            height: 1.0)
                        
                        let aColor: UIColor = UIColor(
                            displayP3Red: 0.0,
                            green: 0.0,
                            blue: 0.0,
                            alpha: CGFloat(aValue))
                        
                        aColor.setFill()
                        UIRectFill(aRect)
                    }
                }
                
                let anImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    self?.imageView.image = anImage
                }
            } else {
                print("nil")
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
}
```

Also this is what the object looks like when printed out! The whole MLMultiArray is not shown because it is too big!

<VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation: 0x282ecbd40> 6A57503A-5613-4C6A-BA14-5DCC7E90F7A4 VNCoreMLRequestRevision1 confidence=1.000000 "var_1027" - "MultiArray : Float32 480 × 320 matrix
[0.0002018213,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6.401539e-05,6.759167e-05,7.200241e-05,7.200241e-05,7.140636e-05,7.140636e-05,7.086992e-05,7.086992e-05,7.033348e-05,6.973743e-05,6.657839e-05,6.711483e-05,6.920099e-05,7.31349e-05,7.843971e-05,8.028746e-05,8.028746e-05,7.724762e-05,7.253885e-05,7.31349e-05,7.486343e-05,7.724762e-05,7.724762e-05,7.426739e-05,7.253885e-05,7.253885e-05,7.367134e-05,7.599592e-05,7.724762e-05,7.784367e-05,8.028746e-05,8.094311e-05.....

Comment: Some models come with built in Input and Output types. You can use those to get what you want.